# Execute MySQL update query on 750k rows

Tags: sql, mysql

I've added a field to a MySQL table. I need to populate the new column with the value from another table. Here is the query that I'd like to run:

```
UPDATE       table1 t1
SET          t1.user_id = 
                        (
                        SELECT   t2.user_id 
                        FROM     table2 t2 
                        WHERE    t2.usr_id = t1.usr_id
                        )
```

I ran that query locally on 239K rows and it took about 10 minutes. Before I do that on the live environment I wanted to ask if what I am doing looks ok i.e. does 10 minutes sound reasonable. Or should I do it another way, a php loop? a better query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an `UPDATE JOIN`! This will provide you a native `inner join` to update from, rather than run the subquery for every bloody row. It tends to be *much* faster.

```
update table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on
    t1.usr_id = t2.usr_id
set t1.user_id = t2.user_id
```

Ensure that you have an index on each of the `usr_id` columns, too. That will speed things up quite a bit.

If you have some rows that don't match up, and you want to set `t1.user_id = null`, you will need to do a `left join` in lieu of an `inner join`. If the column is `null` already, and you're just looking to update it to the values in `t2`, use an `inner join`, since it's faster.

I should make mention, for posterity, that this is MySQL syntax *only*. The other RDBMS's have different ways of doing an `update join`.

Comment: This query needs a `LEFT JOIN` to produce same results (i. e. `NULL`s in absent rows)

Comment: wow! tested the query on 100 rows - avg 650ms. Created index key MUL on usr_id on both tables 100 rows avg 7ms !

Comment: @ed209: It's amazing how much impact little changes can have, eh?

Answer (score 0):

There are two rather important pieces of information missing:

1. What type of tables are they?
2. What indexes exist on them?

If `table2` has an index that contains `user_id` and `usr_id` as the first two columns and `table1` is indexed on `user_id`, it shouldn't be that bad.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an index on `t2.usr_id`.

Create this index and run your query again, or a multiple-table `UPDATE` proposed by `@Eric` (with `LEFT JOIN`, of course).

Note that `MySQL` lacks other `JOIN` methods than `NESTED LOOPS`, so it's index that matters, not the `UPDATE` syntax.

However, the multiple table `UPDATE` is more readable.